# Selection "system default language" in swift programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I have a program which sets the localization for App at run time using the following code:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(["de"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Now if the user selects the option "system default" in my app settings instead of a language I want to set that in my localization.
How is that possible?
Is it like?

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(nil, forKey: "AppleLanguages")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

**EDIT:** I mean setting nil for "AppleLanguages" will choose system default language or the base localization of my App? And how can I make it to select the system default language?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note: do not use `.synchronize()`, it's been obsolete for many versions now. The system automatically writes the values when invoking `setObject.`

Comment: Thanks for the info I'll change and test it now. But my problem is different thing. ;)

Comment: Yeah I know I'm not helping with your issue, sorry - it was just a note, passing by, for you and for future readers. :)